# How do I "Invite" Facebook friends to Like and Share my external URL?

Tags: facebook

I know you can invite friends to your **Facebook Fan Page** via Admin Panel -> Invite Friends.  They all friends get a message with a little orange flag asking them to like the Fan Page.

But how to do the same invite to an **external URL**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

As long as the external URL you mention is a FB app, then the FB.ui dialog call should do it.